# InputText inside Primefaces dataTable is not refreshed

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I need to have inputTexts inside primefaces datatable when form is in editable mode.

Everything works properly except form cleaning with immediate="true" (without form validation). Then primefaces datatable behaves unpredictable. After filling in datatable with new data - it still stores old values.

Short example - to show differences between h:dataTable and p:dataTable - **but it works the same way when there is only one of three tables from the example**:
test.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">

        <p:dataTable var="v" value="#{test.list}" id="testTable">
            <p:column headerText="Test value">
                <p:inputText value="#{v}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <h:dataTable var="v" value="#{test.list}" id="testTable1">
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Test value" />
            </f:facet>
                <p:inputText value="#{v}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>

        <p:dataTable var="v" value="#{test.list}" id="testTable2">
            <p:column headerText="Test value">
                <h:outputText value="#{v}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:commandButton value="Clear" actionListener="#{test.clear()}" immediate="true" update=":form:testTable :form:testTable1 :form:testTable2"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Update" actionListener="#{test.update()}" update=":form:testTable :form:testTable1 :form:testTable2"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<String>            list;



    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        update();
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void clear() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void update() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");     
    }
}
```

In the example above I have 3 configurations:
1. p:dataTable with p:inputText
2. h:dataTable with p:inputText
3. p:dataTable with h:outputText

And 2 buttons: first clears data, second applies data

Workflow:

1. Try to change data in inputTexts in p:dataTable and h:dataTable
2. Clear data of list (arrayList of string) - click "clear" button (imagine that you click cancel on form because you don't want to store data to database)
3. Load new data - click "update" button (imagine that you are openning new form with new data)

**Question:**
Why p:dataTable with p:inputText still stores manually changed data, not the loaded ones?
Is there any way to force p:dataTable to behaving like h:dataTable in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is: **primefaces resetInput**

In my example it would be:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Clear" actionListener="#{test.clear()}" immediate="true"
          update=":form:testTable :form:testTable1 :form:testTable2"> 
    <p:resetInput target=":form:testTable" />
 </p:commandButton>
```

**EDIT:**
In some cases - if the above would not work - try the one from primefaces extensions:

```
<pe:resetInput for=":form:testTable" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're experiencing is when submitting the form, the `#{test.list}` values are being submitted for every datatable (`<p>` or `<h>`) binded to this list in the form. In other words:

- JSF will bind the values of the `testTable` datatable to your `#{test.list}`.
- JSF will bind the values of the `testTable1` datatable to your `#{test.list}`. These values will replace the values binded from `testTable` datatable, and the data there will be lost. `#{test.list}` will contain the data in `testTable1`.
- JSF will bind the values of the `testTable2` datatable to your `#{test.list}`. Since the 
  values here are *the old values*, these will be the values that will be submitted for `#{test.list}`.

The best way to solve this problem is using a single `<p:dataTable>` (or `<h>`, depending on your needs) and an attribute in your managed bean that controls if your table is in view or edit mode.

JSF code

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable var="v" value="#{test.list}" id="testTable">
        <p:column headerText="Test value">
            <h:outputText value="#{v}" rendered="#{not test.editMode}" />
            <p:inputText value="#{v}" rendered="#{test.editMode}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton value="Clear" actionListener="#{test.clear()}" immediate="true"
        update="testTable" />
    <p:commandButton value="Update" actionListener="#{test.update()}"
        update="testTable" />
    <!-- adding a new button just for testing purposes -->
    <p:commandButton value="Submit list" action="#{test.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Managed Bean code

```
//no need of CDI
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private List<String> list;
    private boolean editMode = false;

    public Test() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        update();
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void clear() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void update() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");     
    }

    //method for testing purposes
    public void submit() {
        //in real life web apps, you should log the messages, don't use System.out
        System.out.println("Showing actual values of list attribute.");
        for(String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, but it's not as you said. I posted these three tables to show differences in behaviour of p:dataTable and h:dataTable. But put in my example only one of these tables. p:dataTable will still behave as I described and as I don't like, and h:dataTable will behave as I like. Can you tell me why p:dataTable takes binded empty list from bean (after cleaning) and later takes changes from hand but not from binded list after new list is built and p:dataTable is updated? It remembers values made by hand before list cleaning in the bean.